# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, post

Some time when I call this piece of code *data is nil. It works most of the times except for certain situations which I'm not able to find.

Does anyone know why data could be nil and under which circumstances it could happen?

Some times *data isn't nil but it isn't what I'm expecting (for example I'm getting "login_okit_IT" instead of "login_ok")

Here is the code:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)eseguiRichiestaConURL:(NSString *)urlScript
{

    NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

    NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlScript];



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    //[request setTimeoutInterval:10000];



    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"%@", responseData);


    NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
    //NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

    NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *e;

    if(responseData == nil)
        NSLog(@"------ PARAMETRI VUOI -------");

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:&e];

    return dict;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you use `NSString *rawStr = @""`

Comment: as the first date of the time is nill